# Have to call ray.init() twice: first time gives "AUTH <password> called without any password configured for the default user."

Tags: python, redis, ray

I installed Ray 1.4.1 Python package in a new Python environment. When I tried to start Ray at the command prompt I got the following:

```
>>> import ray
>>> ray.init()
...stack trace...
ResponseError: AUTH <password> called without any password configured for the default user. Are you sure your configuration is correct?
```

If I type `ray.init()` again it works. How do I get it to work the first time?

The stack trace and a search for this error message online both indicate that this is a problem with Redis authentication. The only remedy I could find was to uncomment the `requirepass` line in my `redis.conf`, but this had no effect. If this is an issue with a Redis password, I don't know how to tell Ray what my Redis password is.

*Python 3.9.6, Mac OS X 10.15.7, Redis Server 6.0.8*

Comment: hey, did you find the fix for this?

Comment: I upgraded to Ray 1.6.0 and the problem went away. I never understood what was causing it.

Comment: Thanks! I was already using 1.7 and still faced this issue. I later realised I had a local Redis instance running which I stopped and let ray start its own Redis. Which worked for me. For some reason, it didn't work with the external Redis server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to Ray 1.6.0 fixed this for me.